# Add whole package into Pyinstaller executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to pack my application with `Pyinstaller` but once I pack my `main.py` with `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`, I go into the `dist/` folder and after executing the binary file I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmd.DBQueryCommandLine'; 'cmd' is not a package
[3340308] Failed to execute script main
```

I saw some other questions where people were saying to manually add the directories to the `.spec` file, but I have tons of packages inside the application and I would like to know if there was any other option to recursively include packages into the generated binary.

My application has the following structure:

```
MyApp
|_ module1
  |_some_script.py
|_ module2
  |_submodule2
    |_some_other_script.py
|
... More packages, with sub-packages and .py scripts
|
|_ main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was that `cmd` is a reserved name from a vanilla Python package